# There are only three TV channels on my old TV set. / My old-fashioned TV set has only three channels

Tags: sentence-choice

> There are only three TV channels on my old TV set.
>
> My old TV set has only three channels.

Is it appropriate to use "there are" in this context or only the second version sounds good for native speakers?

Comment: They both mean the same thing and are natural.

Comment: "There are only three TV channels on my old TV set." The first 'TV' is redundant.

Comment: I suspect most would phrase it something like "My old rabbit ears only pick up three channels" (maybe "get" instead of "pick up"). It doesn't matter what kind of TV you're using if the antenna can't receive anything. Could also be "I only get three channels over the air".

Comment: As a US English speaker, I wouldn't say "My TV set only *has* three channels", because that sounds like a TV set "has" or "owns" channels.   I would say "only *gets* three channels" or only *receives* three channels.

Comment: In the UK, we started with 405-line TV on VHF and you only had 1 channel (BBC), no tuner knob or buttons needed. Then in 1954 we got a second commercial channel, (ITV) and new sets had a channel selector with 13 positions (13 possible VHF channels) but only 2 worked in any transmitter zone. In 1964 we got 625 lines on UHF, so a 3rd channel, and in 1982 a 4th (also UHF) channel. By that time new sets were UHF only and usually had 4 channel buttons and people often said 'my TV has 4 channels.'